# What's an easy way to convert legacy Java project with lots of jar libraries to maven project dependency list?

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

I need to convert a legacy project with about 130 jars to a mavenized project. The hardest part seems to creating the pom dependency list. Some of the jars are named with version number like commons-logging-1.1.jar and some are named without like json.jar. What's an easy, auto or semi-auto way to convert this list of jars to maven pom dependency list?

Answer (score 4):

http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch%7Cgav has a very nice feature where you can 'upload' your jars. Based on its checksum it can give you the right groupId, artifactId and version (if it is available at Maven Central of course)

Comment: I think the bulk feature might be gone by now

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic bullet here.  This will be a tedious manual trial-and-error task:

1. Take your best guess as to the dependency version numbers
2. Attempt to build
3. If it builds, attempt to run it
4. If you get errors, go back to step 1 and refine

Once you get it done Maven should make it much easier going forwards.